# Why is the partition vendor reported as "Windows" on a Linux machine

Tags: hard-disk, hardware

I run `lshw` command and among the output is `*-volume:1` which is shown below.

```
 *-volume:1
                description: data partition
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /
                logical name: /.snapshots
                logical name: /opt
                logical name: /var/tmp
                logical name: /usr/local
                logical name: /var/lib/mariadb
                logical name: /boot/grub2/i386-pc
                logical name: /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi
                logical name: /var/cache
                logical name: /srv
                logical name: /var/lib/pgsql
                logical name: /var/opt
                logical name: /var/lib/mysql
                logical name: /var/lib/machines
                logical name: /var/lib/named
                logical name: /var/spool
                logical name: /var/log
                logical name: /var/lib/mailman
                logical name: /var/crash
                logical name: /tmp
                logical name: /var/lib/libvirt/images
                capacity: 332GiB
                configuration: mount.fstype=btrfs mount.options=rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=268,subvol=/@/var/lib/libvirt/images name=primary state=mounted
```

I wonder why the vendor is reported as "Windows" at my `*-volume:1` which I feel like it is my root partition.

Comment: "You feel like" ? What is the output of `mount` and `lsblk` ?

Comment: Because you left the ID at windows, it seems? `fdisk` or `parted` output will probably be easier on the eyes to look at.